# How do I count the number of lines of code in an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to count the number of lines of code in an eclipse project? I can see the total number of lines for each file, but I'd like to see how much is generated across the whole project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the [Eclipse Metrics plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/).

[image]

Note the 'Lines of code' statements.

Edit:
Version 2 of Metrics, requiring Eclipse 3.5+, is available here http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried and it is not working for me. I have installed plugin from Eclipse marketplace, and no luck.. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the JavaNCSS tool, see [JavaNCSS - A Source Measurement Suite for Java](http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/)

I can't find any working links to Eclipse plugins that incorporate this library, only stale broken links.

But you can run it:

- as [an Ant task](http://javancss.codehaus.org/JavancssAntTask.html)
- or as [a Maven plugin](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-javancss-plugin/index.html): `mvn javancss`

Also see [JCSC](http://jcsc.sourceforge.net/) which includes NCSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally just used `find` and `wc` under Cygwin.

Comment: One liner for total count : `find src -type f | xargs cat |wc -l`

Comment: one liner for each file: `for x in $(find src -type f) ; do printf $x ; printf " -> " ; cat $x | wc -l ; done;`

Comment: IMHO this is better since you only count lines of java files and make `find` use `cat` by itself: ```find . -type f -name '*.java' -execdir cat '{}' \; | wc -l```